# ms word dispids for events

Tags: c++, ms-word, com, office-addins, comaddin

I am trying to find a web page that lists all the disp ids for msword c++ addin. I need all the dispids for my event handlers. I am interested in the DocumentEvents, Application events for my add-in. The most important id's that I need are for Open, Close, and New for the documentevents interface. Does anybody know where I can find these? I tried OleView and could not find the id's. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `dispid` in the type library. Looking at a method in the `OLE viewer` use the 'id' which apparently is the `dispid`.

Comment: The OleViewer did not list the id's. Have you tried looking for the MSWORD.OLB?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. You can use OleView, but you have to run it as admin. Once I did that the ID's were visible.

Comment: Yes, I was able to see the IDs. Glad you have already figured this out.